# multiprocessing ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW counter issue

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ctypes

I have a script which every time the function is ran by a process it sets a console title, I did this by setting a lock with a counter based on different conditions. So if it is a success itll add +1 to success counter. After I use more than 2 cores which is what my laptop has, it seems to bug out, it'll start counting backwards and going back and fourth between numbers. I thought setting a lock would fix this but apparently not.

```
#random code here
successlock = Lock()
successvalue = Value('i', 0)
#function starts here, locks and counters are defined outside the function
strin = "f"
if strin = "f":
    with successlock:
        successvalue.value+=1



ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW(str(successvalue.value))
```

Obviously strin has a different value everytime, also i am using multiprocessing Pool, my code works fine its just the counter that bugs out.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the title even when the success case isn't valid. You are also referencing `successvalue` outside of the lock. It also incurs a race condition when two threads are setting the title at the same time.  That might explain why the rollback is happening.

Better solution is to set the title while under the lock.

```
#function starts here, locks and counters are defined outside the function
strin = "f"
if strin = "f":
    with successlock:
        successvalue.value+=1
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW(str(successvalue.value))
```